# How to make checkbox switch change hero background back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

These are the current code snippets.
I tried a few different ways and nothing seems to work.
Please help!!!

HTML Snippet

```
 <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
       <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
       <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

JQuery Snippet

```
var backgroundImg = ['../images/heroBG.jpg', '../images/heroBG2.jpg'
];
var backgroundCount = 0;

$(function () {
    $('hero').css('background', 'url(' + backgroundImg[backgroundCount] + ')');
});

$('myonoffswitch').on('click', function () {
    backgroundCount++;
    if (backgroundCount > backgroundImg.length - 1) backgroundCount = 0;
    $('hero').css('background', 'url(' + backgroundImg[backgroundCount] + ')');
});
```

Comment: Side note; `backgroundCount = ++backgroundCount % backgroundImg.length;` can take care of the incrementing and wrapping of the number back to 0 without the if statement.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you show me how it should look then?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery to reference an element by ID, you need to use #

`$('myonoffswitch')` will check for any `html` element name `myonoffswitch`. To get an element with id `myonoffswitch`, you need to use `$('#myonoffswitch')`

```
$('#myonoffswitch').on('click', function () {
    backgroundCount++;
    if (backgroundCount > backgroundImg.length - 1) backgroundCount = 0;
    //Assuming hero is ID of some element
    $('#hero').css('background', 'url(' + backgroundImg[backgroundCount] + ')');
});
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you. Now I can see the images on the log but it is giving me a 404 (Not Found) for the images which are in my local server. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `background-image` instead of `background`, so your code should be as follows:

```
$('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImg[backgroundCount] + ')');
```

Also, you need a `#` when referencing an ID, so `$('myonoffswitch')` should be `$('#myonoffswitch')` and `$('hero')` should be `$('#hero')`.

Comment: It is working. Thank you. Now I can see the images on the log but it is giving me a 404 (Not Found) for the images which are in my local server. Any clues?

Comment: Where are the images relative to the webpage?

Comment: I have the index.html at same level as a the assets folder, which have 4 folders inside: images, css, docs and JS. Does that answer?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `./assets/images/heroBG.jpg` then instead of `../images/heroBG.jpg`?

Comment: Yes it should. HA! I was using the same path as the css.
Thank you much!

Comment: You do not appear to have read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I would highly advise it, so that you fully understand how the site works.